# I get "posts.map is not a function" ERROR when I delete a post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components

I get "posts.map is not a function this" error when I delete a post, but if I refresh a page it works fine again, any comments or tips on how to fix it?

the function I delete my post with:

```
    const deletePost = (id) => {
        const fetchData = async (id) => {
        await axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/posts/'+id);
        setPosts({
            posts: posts.filter(element => element._id !== id)
        })
        };
        fetchData(id);
        // window.location = '/posts';
      };
```

The function I get error at:

```
      const postList = () => {
            return posts.map(currentPost => {
                return <Post post = {currentPost} deleteExercise={deletePost} key={currentPost._id} />
            })
        };
```

Component I call delete function:

```
const Post = props => 
(
    <ul>
        <li>Date: {props.post.createdAt}</li>
        <li>Title: {props.post.title}</li>
        <li>Your Post: {props.post.postBody}</li>
        <li>
            <Link to={'/edit/' + props.post._id}> edit </Link>| <a onClick={() => props.deletePost(props.post._id)} > Delete </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
)
```

The function I get all my posts from DB:

```
 const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const username = localStorage.getItem("username");
        axios.get('http://localhost:5000/posts/')
            .then(post => {
                setPosts(post.data.filter( x => x.username === username))
            })
       }, []);
```

Comment: After you `delete` something you should refetch it, what happens if there is an error? You filter the array anyway which is stale data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that u declate the posts as an object:

```
setPosts({
        posts: posts.filter(element => element._id !== id)
    })
```

instead to as you do in the fetch :

```
setPosts( posts.filter(element => element._id !== id))
```